# Energy cost conversion

Tags: energy

If electricity costs $0.06 per kilowatt-hour and is used for electric heating with an efficiency of 100%, what is the equivalent price of natural gas per gigajoule if it can be burned with an efficiency of 80%?

(A) $8.00/GJ (B) $13.30/GJ

(C) $15.10/GJ (D) $21.20/GJ

(E) $24.30/GJ

The Book Answer:
($0.06/kWh) x (277. 8 kWh/GJ) = ($16.67/GJ) = ($ X/GJ) x (1/0.8)

X = $13.30/GJ.

My Answer:
($0.06/kWh) x (277. 8 kWh/GJ) = ($16.67/GJ) = ($ X/GJ) x (0.8)

X = $20.833/GJ.

My reasoning is:

If the efficiency of the natural gas was also 100%,

Then, 1 GJ of natural gas energy would cost  $16.67.

Since the natural gas is burned with an efficiency of 80% this requires increasing the amount of natural gas burnt to produce the same energy as 100% efficient electric heating.

Therefore, at an efficiency of 80%

1 GJ of natural gas energy would cost

$16.67/0.8 = $20.833/GJ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about electrical engineering at all; it's high-school math (rule of proportion) that happens to involve electrical energy as one of the sizes.

Comment: @Marcus Müller why do you always feel you have to find a fault with my questions? You spend time reading and writing a reply that isn't helpful. I know that you have great knowledge, I read your replies. FYI I spend 3 hours trying to solve the question. If all of us are as knowledgeable as you and the other top 1% we won't need such forums. At least consider the feelings of others please!

Comment: I don't  feel like this; I honestly don't even recognize you. this is just not an appropriate question for here. If it takes three hours to apply the rule of proportion, that doesn't bode well for your math basics, honestly. This is a level of math that we really expect you to be able to do yourself!

Comment: If you need more of something less efficient to do a job, do you need it to be cheaper, or more expensive, to match the same overall price?

Comment: @Marcus Müller I want to ask you questions in private how can I text you? I want to know what are good reference books so I can purchase them if you don't mind.

Comment: not at all! Please keep questions on here :) that's what this siteis for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I reformulate the question, it is: "what is the price of a kWh of gaz (neglecting losses) so that it cost me the same whether I use electricity of gas to heat my home".

So if gas is less efficient, I need more gas to get the same heat. So if I want to pay the same amount, gas needs to be cheaper.